# Attribute error: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence' PYTHON/SMARTSHEET SDK

Tags: python, attributeerror, smartsheet-api

I installed the Smartsheet Python sdk, imported the smartsheet module but am getting an error when I want to run the script. The error is localized to the smartsheet module and says that collections module is missing Mutable Sequence. I have already tried adding:

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence
```

and had no change.

```
import smartsheet
import logging
import os

_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

This is what pops up in the terminal.

```
 File "C:\Users\jhorvath\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .models import Error, ErrorResult
  File "C:\Users\jhorvath\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\smartsheet\models\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .access_token import AccessToken
  File "C:\Users\jhorvath\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\smartsheet\models\access_token.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..types import *
  File "C:\Users\jhorvath\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\smartsheet\types.py", line 29, in <module>
    class TypedList(collections.MutableSequence):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'
```

Answer (score 4):

A "quick and dirty" solution (I have this one - Python 3.10):
Path you-python-installation\python\Lib\site-packages\smartsheet
File
types.py
Line 29

```
class TypedList(collections.MutableSequence):
```

Replace with

```
class TypedList(collections.abc.MutableSequence):
```

I think Сolleagues from smartsheet - will fix the compatibility problem (at least - I believe it)
The main reason is
[Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! I edited my original post. Those lines underneath the code are the error message/console output, not my actual code. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

If you are not able to edit the package as recommended in the first solution, use Python 3.9 that is the last version to support collections Mutable Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I used is to modify the affected .py file in downloaded library from Smartsheet and change

```
import collections
```

to

```
import collections.abc as collections
```